# Meaning of 悠了一把

Tags: meaning, topolect

see 今日说法, legal report, https://tv.cctv.com/2024/03/17/VIDEi0lCKhnIK1fZ0MuQch5J240317.shtml?spm=C31267.PdQGws28DOXv.E25JptH8Kkey.22 9:30
according to web seems to belong to 东北话

---

悠 HSK 5 English Definition: long or drawn out; remote in time or space; leisurely; to swing; may be standard, note context, 9:30:就已经悠了一把 follows 9:23:一百多公里时速,9:25:九辆车迎面遭遇,9:27:妻儿老小惊慌失措,9:29:这五口人, and is followed by 9:31:就整个悠醒了, meaning: has been happening (to us) for a while (一把 a time)

2 phrases 就已经悠了一把,就整个悠醒了 containing 悠 are spoken by driver appearing only between 9:29 and 9:31, and 就整个悠醒了 may only be a clarification of 就已经悠了一把, where 一把 may mean "at once, immediately". Users most likely would better understand the use of 晃 in this context (see answer).

Answer (score 1):

The video describes the event of a driver facing a reverse-traffic vehicle at high speed in the Shangxi Province. Later, the driver told the police about this encounter:

"...一百多公里時速, 妻兒老小驚慌失措, 這五口人就已經悠了一把, 就整個悠醒了."

I think "悠" meant "晃" for this case:

- 悠 - 在空中摆动：～荡。晃～。转～。- shaking (back and forth in the air).

Answer (score 1):

[悠](https://cantoneseplus.com/character/3082)

> swing; sway; float about

'搖'/yáo/(shake) and '悠/yōu/(sway)' have similar pronunciations, so there is a good chance that the subtitle group made a mistake. Either they thought they heard 悠, or failed to deduct the speaker's pronunciation might be off

It is more logical that someone would wake up by a shake than a sway. Not to mention 悠 is not commonly used as a verb in day-to-day speech, and its main meaning is "leisurely"

When watching videos, I often spot [subtitle mistakes](https://vocus.cc/article/61974d09fd89780001d53b8c), especially in low-budget productions